# How to speed up SQL script which creates a large table of AlphaNumeric codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have the following script, that generates 175 Million(!) unique Alphanumeric codes in the format 'ABC-1234', ranging from AAA-0000 to ZZZ-9999.

Running this script as-is, on my dedicated MS SQL 2016 box takes 20 hours. What's the best way to speed this up? As you can tell from the script, my SQL skills are somewhat lacking !

There's an Identity (int) Column, ID, and the column for the CODE (nvarchar(20)) itself. The two columns make up the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ORDERED_CODES](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Code] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ORDERED_CODES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC,
[Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,                 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The script:

```
DECLARE @Alpha1 INT;
DECLARE @Alpha2 INT;
DECLARE @Alpha3 INT;
DECLARE @Num INT;

-- alpha elements 'ABC'
SET @Alpha1 = 65;
SET @Alpha2 = 65;
SET @Alpha3 = 65;

-- number element '9999'
SET @Num = 0;

-- temporary holders
DECLARE @FINALCODE Nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @CODE1 Nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @CODE2 Nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @CODE3 Nvarchar(50);

WHILE @Alpha1 < 91
BEGIN
   SET @CODE1 = CHAR(@Alpha1)
       WHILE @Alpha2 < 91
        BEGIN
       SET @CODE2 = @CODE1 + CHAR(@Alpha2)
       SET @Alpha2 = @Alpha2 +1
            WHILE @Alpha3 < 91
                BEGIN
                   SET @CODE3 = @CODE2 + CHAR(@Alpha3)
                   SET @Alpha3 = @Alpha3 +1
                        WHILE @Num < 10000
                            BEGIN
                               SET @FINALCODE = RIGHT('0000'+ CAST(@Num as nvarchar(4)),4) + CHAR(45) + @CODE3        
                               SET @Num = @Num +1
                               INSERT INTO ORDERED_CODES (CODE) VALUES (@FINALCODE)
                            END
                        SET @FINALCODE = null
                        SET @Num = 0
                END
            SET @Alpha3 = 65
    END
    SET @Alpha2 = 65

    SET @Alpha1 = @Alpha1 +1   
END;
```

Any and all thoughts are gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Thank you to Gordon, Dan & John for taking the time to help, all are great answers on the same theme so sadly I have to choose one as the answer... so in finest SO tradition it has to go to Gordon for being first. Needless to say I'm going to read up on CTE! The quickest though was Dan's, at nearly 4 minutes on my server - guess I now need to try and work out why my fat server is 5x slower than your desktop! Much better than 20 hours, and I am very grateful. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do:

```
with alphas as (
      select v.ch
      from (values ('A'), ('B'), . . .
           ) v(ch)
     ),
     digits as (
      select v.ch
      from values ('0'), ('1'), . . .
     )
select (a1.ch + a2.ch + a3.ch + d1.ch + d2.ch + d3.ch + d4.ch) as code
from alphas a1 cross join
     alphas a2 cross join
     alphas a3 cross join
     digits d1 cross join
     digits d2 cross join
     digits d3 cross join
     digits d4;
```

The `. . .` is for the valid characters that you want.  You can generate the values using some method other than `values` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of an ad-hoc tally table.  175,760,000 records in 1 minute 6.799 seconds (on my laptop).  Or, 37.833 seconds without the `Order By`

```
;with cteC as (
    Select Top 26 C=char(64+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))) From master..spt_values n1
), cteN as (
Select Top 10000 N= right(concat('0000',Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1),4) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
)
Insert Into Ordered_Codes (Code)
Select Code=Concat(A.C,B.C,C.C,'-',N.N)
 From  cteC A,cteC B,cteC C,cteN N
 Order By 1
```

**cteC** Generates A - Z

**cteN** Generates 0000 - 99999

**The Final Result Looks Like**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I expect a CTE query will perform much better than a loop:

```
WITH 
    alpha_values AS (
        SELECT value FROM(VALUES
             ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M')
            ,('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z'))
            AS alpha_values(value)
    )
    ,t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,number_values AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 AS value FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b CROSS JOIN t10 AS c)
INSERT INTO dbo.ORDERED_CODES (Code)
SELECT

       alpha_values1.value
     + alpha_values2.value
     + alpha_values3.value
     + '-'
     + RIGHT('000' + CAST(number_values.value AS varchar(4)), 4)
     AS Code
FROM alpha_values AS alpha_values1
CROSS JOIN alpha_values AS alpha_values2
CROSS JOIN alpha_values AS alpha_values3
CROSS JOIN number_values
ORDER BY Code;
```

**EDIT**
I didn't see Gordon's similar solution until after I posted. The above query ran in 35 seconds on my desktop.